# Norton security seal in Angular partial

Tags: angularjs, document.write, norton

I have received the html code from Norton

```
<table width="135" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
    title="Click to Verify - This site chose Symantec SSL for secure e-commerce and confidential communications." style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 10px">
    <tr>
        <td width="135" align="center" valign="top">
            <script type="text/javascript-lazy"
                    src="https://seal.websecurity.norton.com/getseal?host_name=myhostname&amp;size=L&amp;use_flash=NO&amp;use_transparent=NO&amp;lang=en" script></script>
            <br />
            <a href="http://www.symantec.com/ssl-certificates" target="_blank" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font: bold 7px verdana,sans-serif; letter-spacing: .5px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">ABOUT SSL CERTIFICATES</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have added the above code in a Angular partial. When I render the page the page the intended Norton image is not showing and console has following error:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened

from the above message I could understand that the script inside html makes call to js file on the remote server which contains document.write which is causing the issue. We can't change the content of the remote file.

I have tried the following github repo but failed to understand the implementation and when used not able to fix the issue.

```
[https://gist.github.com/endorama/7369006][1]
```

Any suggestions/help?

Comment: You could try to overwrite the document write function or look if u can include an other file that supports async loading